# Отобразить миллисекунды при переводе времени в строку в Delphi?

Tags: delphi

Как отобразить миллисекунды в данном коде

В глобальной переменной **Var** пишу:

```
T, T1: TDateTime;
```

В самой процедуре пишу:

```
Begin
................................
////////Перед началом цикла
 T := Time;
................................
///////В конце цикла
ShowMessage( 'Время работы: ' + TimeToStr(Time - T));
```

И у меня результат выводиться в **0:00:00**, то есть часы, минуты, секунды, но нет миллисекунд. Как их добавить?

Comment: для замеров времени выполнения используйте класс `TStopWatch`, емнип

Comment: @teran, Можете привести пример ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6031467/1216425

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.SysUtils.FormatDateTime

Comment: Нормальный вопрос, зачем минусуете? И для обычных циклов, где время выполнения надо прерывать (см. другие вопросы автора) такого способа вполне достаточно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ShowMessage(FormatDateTime('h:n:s.z', T));
```

Выведет время с миллисекундами:

> 08:41:13.004

P.S. Типичная точность замера времени без использования специальных классов - около 16мс (если мне не изменяет память). Стандартная точность хранения миллисекунд в TDateTime около 2-3мсек.